# PythonWin not running

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, installation, pythonwin

Can anyone help? Since moving from Arcmap 10.7 to 10.8
(running Python2.7.18 (v2 )
Window Pop Up message reads:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The error means that the required module is missing. It's a dependency on pywin32 package.
You have to install this package. [What's win32con module in python? Where can I find it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227928/whats-win32con-module-in-python-where-can-i-find-it/39329641) you will find the solutions to resolve this issue.